# How to prove that a language $K_L$ is context-free based off a regular language $L$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

Let $\{a,b\}$ the alphabet $\Sigma$.  If $L$ is a language on alphabet $\Sigma$ then i have 
$$K_L = \{x\,|\,∃y\,|\,(x \sim y \,\land\, y \in L)\}$$
The relation $\sim$ is defined on $\{a,b\}^*$ by $x \sim y$ if $x$ and $y$ have the same number of $a$'s and $b$'s.

So, a word $x \in K_L$ if it can be rearranged to form a word from $L$.
I believe that $K_L = A \:\cap\: L^c$ where $A = \{w \::\: |a| = |b| \}$

If i could get a hint as to how to prove that if $L$ is regular, then $K_L$ is always context-free. And maybe some links to help my comprehension. It would be much appreciated !

Comment: When you say "$x$  and $y$ have the same number of 's and 's", do you mean that  $|x|_a = |y|_a = |x|_b = |y|_b$ or only $|x|_a = |y|_a$ and $|x|_b = |y|_b$? Maybe Parikh's Theorem is of interest to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem

Comment: I mean $|x|_a = |y|_a$ and $|x|_b = |y|_b$ so the number of $a$ and $b$'s are independant. And thank you for the link, i didn't know about Parikh's Theorem. I will look into it

Comment: Consider the regular language $L= (abc)^*$. So $K_L$ is the language that consists of all words that have equal numbers of all three symbols. Now the language $K_L \cap a^*b^*c^* = \{a^nb^nc^n: n\geq 0\}$ is not context-free. Because the context-free languages are closed under intersection with regular languages, $K_L$ cannot be context-free in this case. One symbol more than your case, but it might still be interesting to you.